# ActionView::Template::Error (vendor/modernizr.js isn't precompiled) on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my application to Heroku. It apparently succeeds but when I try running the page I get 'sorry something went wrong' message. I have run the 'heroku logs' command and I see error there that says:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (vendor/modernizr.js isn't precompiled)
```

Content of my Gemfile as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'pg'
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'debugger'
gem 'activerecord-import'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'ruby-prof', group: :test
gem 'test-unit', group: :test

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'    
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

The config/application.rb file contains:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

The config/environments/production.rb contains:

```
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
```

I also refer to the modernizr file in the application.html.erb

```
<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Business manager" %></title>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Please let me know how to get this thing working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the 'modernizr.js' file in the list of assets to precompile.

In environments/production.rb  add it to config.assets.precompile:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(modernizr.js)
```

Comment: I did add that line before and after the 3 lines that were already there and it seems like it had no effect as I am seeing exactly the same error. The thing is that I do not have the modernizr.js file in the assets folder as it would normally use the foundations one. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Set config.assets.compile = true.

Comment: This got rid of the 'sorry something got wrong error' but the css and js that is applied in the local setting, is not applied on production at all. Had a look into the logs and all I see is 200 and 304 statuses, no apparent errors...